# IBOutlet to ChildViewControllers of PageViewController inside a ContainerVIew

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

Below image shows, PageViewController embedded inside a container view, and it has two childViewControllers SIGNIN ViewController and SIGNUP Static TableViewController. Now i want access Textfields and Buttons on ChiildViewControllers(SingIn and SignUp). How and Where i need to access them, How to create IBOutlet for these?.

[image]

Comment: where is your image ?

Comment: you can use different UIVIew for sign in and register for instead of container view .

Comment: please see the link

Comment: in this container view SingIn and SignUp you create 2 uiviewcontroller and give class to that view and create IBOutlet and their action method on that particular viewcontroller.